# How do I change the IP Location in whois lookup?

Tags: ip, whois

I have seen many websites change the IP Location under "Server Stats" in whois lookup like this link http://whois.domaintools.com/kbeezie.com and wouldlike to know how I can do the same.

What do I need to do to achieve this? What do I need?

The IP Location was changed to "**Missouri - Kansas City - Karl Blessing**"

Comment: is this something for nginx web server only? because for some reason most websites i see doing this use nginx

Answer (score 1):

That IP location most likely comes from a GeoIP database. There are a number of services that provide a location for an IP address, typically based on the AS the IP address belongs to and various additional information gathered from the ISP. By far most popular is the MaxMind database.

Part of the purpose of the database is to give a trustworthy location for the data source, so you can not just randomly change it. If you have write access into your RIR database for the block your address belongs to you might be able to change the information there and then have it picked up by the GeoIP suppliers.

Comment: so how to i do that? `"If you have write access into your RIR database for the block your address belongs to you might be able to change the information there and then have it picked up by the GeoIP suppliers."`